# java regular expression and replace all occurrences

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to replace one string in a big string, but my regular expression is not proper I guess. So it's not working.

**Main string is**

Some sql part which is to be replaced

```
cond =  emp.EMAIL_ID = 'xx@xx.com' AND
emp.PERMANENT_ADDR LIKE('%98n%') 
AND hemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'xxx' and is_active='Y'
```

**String to find and replace is**

Based on some condition sql part to be replaced

```
hemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'xxx'
```

**I have tried this with**

Pattern and Matcher class is used and

```
Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("/^hemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME\\s=\\s\'\\w\'\\s[and|or]*/$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        
        Matcher mat = pat1.matcher(cond);
         while (mat.find()) {
                     System.out.println("Match: " + mat.group());
                    cond = mat.replaceFirst("xx "+mat.group()+"x");
                    mat = pat1.matcher(cond);
        
        }
```

It's not working, not entering the loop at all. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the anchors `^` and `$`, you can use word boundaries `\b` to prevent a partial match.

If you want to match spaces on the same line, you can use `\h` to match horizontal whitespace char, as `\s` can also match a newline.

You can use [replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) on the string using `$0` to get the full match, and an inline modifier `(?i)` for a case insensitive match.

**Note** that using `[and|or]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching one of the listed chars and escape the dot to match it literally, or else `.` matches any char except a newline.

```
(?i)\bhemp\.EMPLOYEE_NAME\h*=\h*'\w+'\h+(?:and|or)\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8eRUP/1) or a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/E4rpZc)

For example

```
String regex = "\\bhemp\\.EMPLOYEE_NAME\\h*=\\h*'\\w+'\\h+(?:and|or)\\b";
String string = "cond =  emp.EMAIL_ID = 'xx@xx.com' AND\n"
+ "emp.PERMANENT_ADDR LIKE('%98n%') \n"
+ "AND hemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'xxx' and is_active='Y'";

System.out.println(string.replaceFirst(regex, "xx$0x"));
```

Output

```
cond =  emp.EMAIL_ID = 'xx@xx.com' AND
emp.PERMANENT_ADDR LIKE('%98n%') 
AND xxhemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'xxx' andx is_active='Y'
```

Comment: Thank you. How to match if  there is no space or and|or at the last?

Comment: It may happen that after hemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'xxx' there is nothing. Then this regx is not working. How to do it?

Comment: @mou You could make the last part optional `(?i)\bhemp\.EMPLOYEE_NAME\h*=\h*'\w+'(?:\h+(?:and|or)\b)?` See https://regex101.com/r/v94K6v/1

Comment: Its working in regx editor  but Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 26
(?i)\bhemp\.EMPLOYEE_NAME\h*=\h*'\w+'(?:\h+(?:and|or)\b)? in java. When I replace it with \s its not working.

Comment: @mou In Java, you have to double escape the backslashes `String regex = "(?i)\\bhemp\\.EMPLOYEE_NAME\\h*=\\h*'\\w+'(?:\\h+(?:and|or)\\b)?";`

Comment: double escape also not working..it seems \\h is not valid.. its taking \\s but then there is no match.

Comment: @mou The double escapes for `\\h` work, this is Java right? See https://ideone.com/s7PC3f

Comment: yes..but its throwing error mentioned in my earlier comment.. Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 26 (?i)\\bhemp\\.EMPLOYEE_NAME\\h*=\\h*'\\w+'(?:\\h+(?:and|or)\\b)? point towards \h. I have tried ur mentioned one also.

Comment: @mou Can you just run this code and see if that by itself works? https://ideone.com/s7PC3f

Comment: Yes its working but my requirement is replace all such strings with something else. So I have used String regex = "(?i)\\bhemp\\.EMPLOYEE_NAME\\h*=\\h*'\\w+'(?:\\h+(?:and|or)\\b)?";     
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cond);
  while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
         for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
           System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
 }} where in first line itself its throwing error.

Comment: very strange..in single file its pattern matcher also working but when added the code in spring 3.0 framework controller class then its not working

Comment: Atlast I understood the problem..problem is not with regx...its the string that is passed dyanmically.. emp.EMAIL_ID = 'mousumibhod@nrifintech.com' AND
emp.PERMANENT_ADDR LIKE('%98n%') AND
pemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME = 'mousumi bhowmick'

Comment: @mou That means that the pattern works for the given example, but you have to take into account what the dynamic string could be.

Comment: Yes pattern and java code both worked..I have misunderstood the dynamic data and thought it was not working..Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not - your regexp pattern doesn't make any sense.

- The opening `/`: In some languages, regexps aren't strings and start with an opening slash. **Java is not one of those languages**, and it has nothing to do with regexps itself. So, this looks for a literal slash in that SQL, which isn't there, thus, failure.
- `^` is regexpese for 'start of string'. Your string does not start with hemp.EMPLOYEE_NAME, so that also doesn't work. Get rid of both / and ^ here.
- `\\s` is one whitespace character (there are many whitespace characters - this matches any one of them, exactly one though). Your string doesn't have any spaces. Your intent, surely, was `\\s*` which matches 0 to many of them, i.e.: `\\s*` is: "Whitespace is allowed here". `\\s` is: There must be exactly one whitespace character here. Make all the `\\s` in your regexp an `\\s*`.
- `\\w` is exactly one 'word' character (which is more or less a letter or digit), you obviously wanted `\\w*`.
- `[and|or]` this is regexpese for: "An a, or an n, or a d, or an o, or an r, or a pipe symbol". Clearly you were looking for `(and|or)` which is regexpese for: Either the sequence "`and`", or the sequence "`or`".
- `*` - so you want 0 to many 'and' or 'or', which makes no sense.
- closing slash: You don't want this.
- closing `$`: You don't want this - it means 'end of string'. Your string didn't end here.

The code itself:

`replaceFirst`, itself, also does regexps. You don't want to double apply this stuff. That's not how you replace a found result.

This is what you wanted:

```
Matcher mat = pat1.matcher(cond);
mat.replaceFirst("replacement goes here");
```

where replacement can include references to groups in the match if you want to take parts of what you matched (i.e. don't use `mat.group()`, use those references).

More generally did you read any regexp tutorial, did any testing, or did any reading of the javadoc of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/package-summary.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/package-summary.html)?

I've been developing for a few years. It's just personal experience, perhaps, but, reading is pretty fundamental.